# Sub events in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show sub events in calendar. Currently I am using FullCalendar, it servers most of my purpose but now I've requirement to show sub events. Here is what I need.[image]

If this is not possible in FullCalendar, then please suggest me some other Jquery Calendar which can serve the purpose.

Comment: You need to workout to get this functionality, I don't think you'll get exact same feature in any JS library.

Comment: thanks, but do you know any other calender feature which will let me do this

Comment: You could do this with a significant amount of work. I can write up a basic algorithm outline if you like, but it'd take me too long to write the code for it.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? i am searching my self and cant find